# Configure a cisco ASA 5550 behind a modem

Tags: cisco

i have an internet box that i can setup in router mode or bridge mode.
Then i have an ASA 5550, that i would like to use as a vpn server (anyconnect) + later site to site connected to another asa 5550.

I think that i am stuck at the level 0.

I setup my modem as bridge and as dmz target i specify one of the ASA ethernet port ip (same mask), i connect the modem directly to this port and then... i don't know what to do.

If this even possible or should i keep my modem as router and just NAT all the ports required for the VPN features to my ASA ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASA5550 was End Of Life in 2018](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/obsolete/security/cisco-asa-5550-adaptive-security-appliance.html), and End of Sale in 2013.

## DO NOT USE IT. IT IS NOT SECURE.

Seriously. Get some solution that is actually still supported, such as PFSense with OpenVPN or Wireguard.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't paid attention indeed...